# How to automatically do software deployments on remote devices

Tags: azure-devops, deployment, raspberry-pi, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I have `raspberry pi` devices installed at client location. We have 7 `pi` devices installed. Each device runs a `systemd` service which invokes python code. This python code basically gets data from client's machine, process it and uploads it to portal.

We keep on developing more features in our python code and all the source code is maintained in `azure devops` repository. Once fully tested, we have to manually deploy the code in each `pi` device. We follow below steps:

```
1. Connect to raspberry pi device using VNC.
2. Stop the running systemd services
3. Using git pull, get all the latest changes from the main branch from azure repository
4. Test & validate (if required)
5. Restart the systemd services
```

This takes a lot of time and doing the same steps for each device takes whole day.

We are looking for an automatic solution for remote deployments such that, once we push latest changes in `main` branch, code should be automatically deploy in our `pi` devices. This definitely would require some software to be installed on `pi` devices which will always be connected to `azure devops` so that it knows when changes are pushed and it can trigger the same action on `pi` device.

Can anyone please provide some good solutions as I am unable to figure out to design a CI CD azure pipeline for remote deployment on `raspberry pi` devices. Thanks

Comment: Azure DevOps agent running somewhere that gets triggered by an Azure DevOps release pipeline? And it simply just installs the changes to all the devices?

Comment: @JamesZ Yes is that not possible? I have seen people doing this for web api's?

Comment: Sound simple. Don't really see what the problem is here...

Comment: @JamesZ I don't have articles which explains on how to setup this. Can you share some links articles?

Comment: I don't have anything I can recommend, but I'm sure there's plenty of articles and even youtube videos. Examples that are shown typically use the built in templates for building & deploying things, but you can always use a blank template and just run for example python scripts. Also some of the names have changed over the few years, like builds is now called just "pipelines". yaml is now the default, which might be a bit scary looking, but also a good thing to learn, but you can still use the classic GUI editor without yaml.